# NFS & Lion connection is not working

Tags: ubuntu, osx-lion, nfs

I am a web developer and I'm trying to establish a workflow between OSX Lion ( Design + Development ), Parallels + Ubuntu preproduction server.

I am trying to create a connection to share files ( images, js, css, etc... ) in a fast way, but I cannot achieve to create a NFS connection.

NOTE: You can share folders in Parallels, but due to later problems with GIT and SVN ( doesn't  follow symlinks ) I need to find an alternative.

OK, that said:

I have to machines:

VM Ubuntu Server: 10.211.55.5
Client: 192.168.1.3

Ubuntu server conf:

```
/etc/hosts.allow
ALL:192.168.1.3/255.255.255.0
```

**(Not really sure how masks are working)**

```
/etc/export
/path/to/folder 192.168.1.3(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

I executed:

```
sudo exportfs -ra
sudo /etc/init.d/portmap restart
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-common <- This is command not found althought I installed it using aptitude
```

Finally this is what I execute on Lion:
sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,vers=4 10.211.55.5:/nfs /home
with the answer "mount_nfs: can't mount /nfs from 10.211.55.5 onto /home: Permission denied"

*I also tried via Finder ( Command-K - Network Connection ) and via Disk Utility ( NFS Connection, this last one says the connection is ok, but the only thing it does is to hide the  local folder until the connection is removed again... )*

I tried commands like:

```
showmount -e 10.211.55.5
```

**showmount: Cannot retrieve info from host: 10.211.55.5: RPC: Program not registered**

and

```
rpcinfo -p 10.211.55.5
```

**No remote programs registered.**

I thing I pretty much gave you all the information I got.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Ok I found the solution, this is my current configuration:

```
VM Ubuntu Server: 10.211.55.5 
From OSX Lion: 192.168.1.3
```

From VM Ubuntu Server

Exports

```
sudo vi /etc/exports
/path/to/folder *(rw,sync,subtree_check,insecure)
```

Hosts allow

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts.allow
#empty
```

Hosts deny

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts.deny
#empty
```

Restart servers:

```
chown nobody:nogroup /path/to/folder
exportfs -a
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
sudo /etc/init.d/portmap restart
```

Finally from OSX Lion

```
sudo mount -t nfs  10.211.55.5:/path/to/folder /local/folder/
```

Hope it helps someone else!